# asp.net mvc nhibernate unit testing

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nhibernate, testing, fluent

How can I write a unit test  for CRUD using in memory database with fluent nhibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't write a unit test (which by the standard definition does not involve external systems).

Instead you would write an integration test and I think this is what you're looking for..

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing

Comment: Thanks that help, I did find a way of doing it but your link answered alot of questions also